# How to pass parameter to testng xml through command line

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

I am executing my selenium automation scripts through testng, for the same I am having a testng xml form where I am passing parameter values like which test case has to be executed and on which environment it has to be executed.

E.g of testng xml is pasted below

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Automation Suite">
<parameter name="tags" value="MyTestCase"/>
    <!-- Default suite -->    
<test name="GGGGG Automation Test" verbose="2">
<parameter name="Environment" value="MyEnvironment" />
<classes>
<class name="com.XXXXX.TestRunner.XXXXXX"/>
   </classes>
 </test>  
</suite>**
```

here I am passing 2 parameters like test cases and environment to be executed form testng example. I am looking for a command line 'command' to execute the testng xml passing those 2 parameters from commandline argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using JVM arguments you can pass in parameters, such as -Dname=Environment. This has been answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266606/how-to-pass-parameter-to-testng-xml-from-command-line-with-maven).

[This blog post has examples](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2017/09/29/dynamic-parameterization-in-testng/)

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your response. I already seen this method, it is given for the maven. I am not using maven in my project. Do you have any alternate solution for this without using maven. My TestNG command line looks like this "java -cp lib\*;bin org.testng.TestNG -DEnvironment="QA" TestNGRunner.xml"

Comment: @Shyam - Irrespective of whether you use Maven or not, the approach is the same.

Comment: Its working fine, I was trying without removing the @Parameter tag. after removing it, it is working fine

Comment: It worked , I also passed multiple parameters.              mvn clean install -Dbrowser="Chrome" -Dbrowser_version="89.0" -Dos_version="10" -Dos="Windows" -Dlocalrun="true"  -Dtestxml=src/test/TestSuites/BrowserStackMultiFramework.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a groupName to be run at runtime in TestNG XML using Beanshell.

For details, please refer: http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/07/15/advanced-testng-tutorials-34-how-to-pass-a-group-name-to-be-run-at-runtime-in-testng-xml-using-beanshell/